# How can we pass a variable to where clause in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pass a variable SCD_filter to the where clause in the dataframe in spark for which I am receiving an error but when passed directly its working fine.I am doing this to dynamically pass this filter based on different scenarios for future use.

```
  val SCD_filter = """currentDF.col("u_business_unit") <=> updatedDF.col("u_business_unit")
                     |      and(currentDF.col("u_operation_level_2") <=> updatedDF.col("u_operation_level_2"))
                     |      and(currentDF.col("u_operation_level_3") <=> updatedDF.col("u_operation_level_3"))""".stripMargin
```

I am then passing the variable to the code below:

```
val common_unchangedata = currentDF.alias("currentDF")
.join(updatedDF, currentDF.col("Sys_id") === updatedDF.col("Sys_id"), "inner")
.select("currentDF.*")
.where(s"$SCD_filter")  /// passing the variable which is causing the error
.show()
```

Error Received:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'currentdf' not found;
```

Note: the currentDF is fine as the code is executing when variable is removed and we pass the condition to the where clause instaed of variable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpwFt.png)

Comment: that variable should be in `Column` type

Comment: can you post full code ?

Comment: The sample code is present

Comment: how are you creating ```updatedDF``` where is this code ?? post complete code else its difficult find issue

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
val common_unchangedata = currentDF.alias("currentDF")
.join(updatedDF, currentDF.col("Sys_id") === updatedDF.col("Sys_id"), "inner")
.select("*")
.where($"Column1='$data'")  /// passing the variable which is causing the error
.show()
```

Comment: actually I have to parametrize the entire where condition as its has to be a generic script for loading multiple tables in which the where condition itself will be different for different tables..the condition will be a comparison between columns of two dataframes(currrent and updated)

Comment: The number of columns will be dynamic so the where and and clause will changes for different tables like for one tables 3 columns will be present in where while for another 6 columns comparison needs to be done

Comment: ahk. got it. Unfortunately .where or .filter does not support CASE-WHEN clause like it does with .select... Would you like to bring this logic one level above and define DF with appropriate 'hard-coded' column_name based the condition?

Comment: actually this code will be running for 5 tables and all tables will be having different columns and all conditions will be different..I am open for a better approach aswell

Answer (score 0):

Create alias for both `DataFrames` & use alias like `alias.column_name` inside string.

```
val SCD_filter = """
   (
     (currentDF.u_business_unit <=> updatedDF.u_business_unit) and 
     (currentDF.u_operation_level_2 <=> updatedDF.colu_operation_level_2) and 
     (currentDF.u_operation_level_3 <=> updatedDF.u_operation_level_3)
   )
"""
```

```
val common_unchangedata = currentDF.alias("currentDF")
.join(updatedDF, currentDF.col("Sys_id") === updatedDF.col("Sys_id"), "inner")
.select("currentDF.*")
.where(SCD_filter)
.show()
```

Comment: same error what is mentioned in the problem statement..although currentDF is present it is not able to read it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> actually this code will be running for 5 tables and all tables will be having different columns and all conditions will be different..I am open for a better approach aswell

I would solve this problem with something like this,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val cond1 = $"u_business_unit"     <=> $"updatedDF.u_business_unit"
val cond2 = $"u_operation_level_2" <=> $"updatedDF.u_operation_level_2"
val cond3 = $"u_operation_level_3" <=> $"updatedDF.u_operation_level_3"

val SCD_filter = cond1.and(cond2).and(cond3)

val common_unchangedata = currentDF
.join(updatedDF, currentDF.col("Sys_id") === updatedDF.col("Sys_id"), "inner")
.where(SCD_filter) 
.show()
```

You could extend this to have a function `getCondition(tableName:String):Column` which constructs the appropriate condition in runtime based on which type of data you are working with.